# Canvas disappear with soft keyboard on android

Tags: javascript, canvas

i've made a little script where a canvas is drawn dynamically according to user input(type:number), it needs work but the issue is that on android devices, when the user hide the soft keyboard, the canvas is erased. is it a way to prevent that ? Thx for any help
here is the code

```
        var form = document.querySelector("form"),
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
positions = [];

if (!canvas) {
alert("Impossible de récupérer le canvas");
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
    canvas.height = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
} else {
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 600;
}
});

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
if (!context) {
alert("Impossible de récupérer le contexte");
}

form.addEventListener("input", function () {

var table = form.table.value,
    modulo = form.modulo.value,
    centerX = canvas.width / 2,
    centerY = canvas.height / 2,
    rayon = (canvas.width - 5) / 2;
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = "#21A8A3";

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);

for (var i = modulo; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    var angle = (2 * Math.PI / modulo) * i - (Math.PI / 2);
    positions[i] = {
        x: centerX + rayon * Math.cos(angle),
        y: centerY + rayon * Math.sin(angle)
    };
}

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, rayon, 0, Math.PI * 2);
var j = positions.length - 1;
for (j; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
    var next = j * table;
    context.moveTo(positions[j].x, positions[j].y);

    context.lineTo(positions[next % modulo].x, positions[next % modulo].y);
}
context.stroke();
});
```

and the url :http://multiplier.hyperion-web.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tried on an Android device, but your problem is more likely due to your bad resize event listener.

This handler do resize your canvas at each `resize` event, but it doesn't call again your drawing functions, which leaves you with an empty canvas, since modifying the `width` and `height` of a canvas resets its context (it does clear it, but also resets any properties like `fillStyle`, transformation matrix, clipping area etc).

Calling and hiding the soft keyboard will fire a `resize` event.

So the solution for you is to fix your event handler so that it does redraw everything after it has set the new dimensions of your canvas.

For this you'll have to store your drawing function in a separate variable, then attach it to your input event, and make a call to it in your resize event listener.

*Ps : even setting the `width` or `height` attributes to the same value they were will reset the whole context*